# How to use tkinter after() to create rectangles one at a time?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program that takes a 2d array. Inside of the array are values of "GREEN" or "BLACK". BLACK or GREEN depends on a density variable, which is edittable via the textbox on the screen. I create a canvas, and then create a 1x1 rectangle for each index of my array, coloring it either black or green. After that, what I want to do is reiterate through my array, and set my green rectangles to red. Also, if any rectangles to the North, East, South, and West are green, I want to also set them to red. This is where my question comes in. I want to do this last step one rectangle at a time, and update my screen so I can slowly see the rectangles change from green to red. How can I do it step by step instead of all at once? I've tried using the after() method in a couple places, but haven't gotten it to change the program behavior. Please let me know if you have any ideas. My latest attempt is this:

```
root.after(5)
```

On line 61. Here is my full code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

# 150 x 150 array, initialized all cells to 0-1
a, b = 150, 150;
density = .5

def RedOrGreen():
  c = random.uniform(0,1)
  if c > density:
    d = "GREEN"
  else:
    d = "BLACK"
  return d

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.density_label = tk.Label(text = "Tree Density")
        self.density_label.pack(side="top")
        self.density_textbox = tk.Entry(bd = 5)
        self.density_textbox.pack(side = "top")
        self.setup = tk.Button(bottomframe, text = "Setup", command = self.setupClick)
        self.setup.pack(side="bottom")
        self.forest = tk.Canvas(self, width = 500, height = 500)

    def setupClick(self):
        print(self.density_textbox.get())
        global density
        density = float(self.density_textbox.get())
        Matrix = [[RedOrGreen() for x in range(a)] for y in range(b)]
        for x in range(a):
            for y in range(b):
                self.forest.create_rectangle(x,y,x+1,y+1, fill = Matrix[x][y], width = 0)
        self.forest.pack()
        for x in range(a):
            for y in range(b):
                if x != 0 and x != 149 and y != 0 and y != 149:
                  if Matrix[x][y] == "GREEN":
                    Matrix[x][y] = "RED"
                    #north
                    if Matrix[x][y-1] == "GREEN":
                        Matrix[x][y-1] = "RED"
                    #east
                    if Matrix[x+1][y] == "GREEN":
                        Matrix[x+1][y] = "RED"
                    #south
                    if Matrix[x][y+1] == "GREEN":
                        Matrix[x][y+1] = "RED"
                    #west
                    if Matrix[x-1][y] == "GREEN":
                        Matrix[x-1][y] = "RED"
        for y in range(b):
            for x in range(a):
                self.forest.create_rectangle(x,y,x+1,y+1, fill = Matrix[x][y], width = 0)
                #root.after(5)

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()
bottomframe = tk.Frame(root)
bottomframe.pack(side = "bottom")
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Put `root.update()` there where you commented that *after.* Add `time.sleep(n)` if needed.

Comment: `root.after(5)` works like `time.sleep` - it blocks `mainloop()` which redraws elements in window. You may have to use `root.update()` after `after()` to redraw elements in window.

Comment: `root.after(5)` only pauses for 5 **milliseconds** — you might want a longer delay.